# Alterar e deletar objetos antes de persistir em BD

Tags: java, java-ee, arquitetura-de-software

Tenho uma funcionalidade que tem como objetivo o cadastro de clientes, na qual dentro de tal cadastro tenho um relacionamento da seguinte forma:

**Um cliente pode ter vários "Atendimentos", sendo que cada atendimento pode conter vários destinos e/ou acompanhantes relacionados.**

Ou seja, um cliente pode entrar em minha "Agência" (o sistema no qual estou empenhado em desenvolver trata-se de um **CRM** para agências de viagem), e o funcionário abrir um "Atendimento" para aquele cliente.

Com o atendimento aberto eu vou ter o cadastro tanto de "Acompanhantes" (relacionado com quem o cliente irá viajar), assim como os "Destinos", no qual o cliente tem um potencial interesse.

Tal cadastro se da pela abertura de um modal em que vou ter alguns campos básicos para preenchimento e que serão passados via **AJAX** para minha action, logo essa action irá armazenar os objetos dentro de uma lista que posteriormente quando o usuário do sistema terminar todo o cadastro do "Atendimento" irá salvar, persistindo os dados no BD.

Ok, até ai não tive problema algum. O bicho começa a pegar quando tenho que editar ou até mesmo deletar tal objeto, pois o mesmo se encontra em uma lista sem *id's* para identificação e tratamento. Um outro problema é que se dou "*refresh*" na pagina minha lista fica "populada" com os dados no qual o usuário digitou anteriormente tornando-se inconsistente.

Uma outra alternativa na qual eu estava pensando em fazer (e talvez a mais correta), seria de que toda vez que fosse realizado algum cadastro de "destinos" ou "acompanhantes" quando eu realizasse minha chamada **AJAX** (passando para a action as informações), eu persistiria imediatamente, mas esse método trás outro problema também. E caso o usuário desistisse de concretizar o atendimento? Logicamente meu banco iria ficar com registros órfãos, sem contar que estou querendo persistir uma lista e não faz muito sentido para mim ficar persistindo um objeto a cada **Request**.

Não sei se consegui ilustrar exatamente o problema, mas a questão principal é qual seria a forma correta de atualizar tais objetos, antes de persistir a entidade pai.

### EDIÇÃO

Abaixo encontra-se as três entidades envolvidas no processo:

1ª Temos abaixo a entidade `Customer.java`, no caso ela pode conter vários `customerService`.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_customer")
    private Long idCustomer;

    @Column(name = "birth_date")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @NotNull(message = "A data de nascimento não pode estar vazia!")
    private Date birthDate;

    @Column(name = "email")
    @NotEmpty(message = "O E-mail não pode estar vazio!")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    @NotEmpty(message = "O Nome não pode ser vazio!")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "gender")
    private char gender;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_document")
    private Document document;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_customerPhone")
    private CustomerPhone customerPhone;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_customer")
    private Set<Passenger> passenger;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_customerAddress")
    private CustomerAddress customerAddress;

    @Column(name = "observations")
    private String observations;

    //Um Cliente pode ter varios atendimentos.
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_customer")
    private Set<CustomerService> customerService;

    public Customer() {
    }

    // Getter Setter
```

2º `CustomerService.java` que por sua vez tem uma lista de `destinationRequested`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer_service")
public class CustomerService implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_customer_service")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "date_service")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date date;

    @Column(name = "average_budget")
    private BigDecimal averageBudget;

    @Column(name="service_situation")
    private boolean situation;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_customer_service")
    private Set<DestinationRequested> destinationRequested;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_history")
    private History history;

    @Column(name = "service_observatons")
    private String serviceObservations;

    // Getter Setter
```

3º Por ultimo temos a entidade de `RequestedDestination.java` que é equivalente aos destinos negociados em cada atendimento

```
@Entity
@Table(name="destination_requested")
public class DestinationRequested implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id_destination_requested")
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private Double price;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name="sale_type")
    private SaleType saleType;

    @Column(name="departure_date")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date departureDate;

    @Column(name="arrival_date")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date arrivalDate;

    //Getter and Setter
```

Comment: Boa tarde. Tem como postar o código das suas Entidades? Acredito que basta um ajuste em seus relacionamentos para resolver o seu problema, mas para isso você precisa colocar as suas entidades. Pode fazer isso? Obrigado

Comment: Oi @GilvanAndré, editei a pergunta com as entidades.

Answer (score 1):

Ola.

Eu verifiquei as entidades e contatei que você não possui as relações ManyToOne de CustomerService para Customer e de DestinationRequested para CustomerService. Eu mudei um pouco as classes e estou postando aqui com comentário nas alterações realizadas.

As únicas que precisaram de ajustes foram essas:

CustomerService

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer_service")
public class CustomerService {
     private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_customer_service")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "date_service")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date date;

    @Column(name = "average_budget")
    private BigDecimal averageBudget;

    @Column(name="service_situation")
    private boolean situation;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_customer_service")
    private Set<DestinationRequested> destinationRequested;

    @Column(name = "service_observatons")
    private String serviceObservations;

    //VOCE DEVE RELACIONAR MUITOS PARA UM O CUSTOMER
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", referencedColumnName = "id_customer")
    private Customer customer;
}
```

DestinationRequested

```
@Entity
@Table(name="destination_requested")
public class DestinationRequested {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id_destination_requested")
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private Double price;


    @Column(name="departure_date")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date departureDate;

    @Column(name="arrival_date")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date arrivalDate;


    //VOCE DEVE RELACIONAR MUITOS PARA UM O CUSTOMERSERVICE
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", referencedColumnName = "id_customer_service")
    private CustomerService customerService;
}
```

Apos realizar as alterações testei elas e estão funcionando.
Qualquer coisa da um grito ai.
Abraços

Comment: Ola. Você já conseguiu resolver o seu problema?